# Problems when test whether standard input is capable of seeking

Tags: api

I reversed statements in `if/else`, corrected now.

---

I am reading a code snippet from *Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment*:

> The program  tests its standard input to see whether it is capable of seeking.

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

    if(lseek(STDIN_FILENO,0, SEEK_CUR) == -1)
        printf("cannot seek\n");
    else{
        printf("seek ok\n");
    }
}
```

I compile and run it (under `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`) but don't understand the following behaviors.

```
//1
$ ./a.out 
cannot seek

//2
$ ./a.out < /etc/passwd
seek OK

//3
$ cat < /etc/passwd | ./a.out
cannot seek

//4
$ ./a.out < /var/spool/cron/FIFO
cannot seek
```

Why `//1` is `cannot seek`? Empty `stdin` should be able to seek I think. Is it because `stdin` has not been opened yet? Because I heard that normally `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are opened when a program starts to run.

Why `//2` is OK and `//3` is not? I think they are the same.

Comment: I just found out that Unix C API calls is ontopic here :).

Comment: I can't reproduce your `seek OK` with the given program on OpenBSD (`cat file | ./a.out` returns `seek OK` though).  There's something wonky about the code. The terminal device (which is attached to the `a.out` process when no redirection is done) is not seekable.

Comment: //1 doesn't have an "empty stdin", but a stdin connected to the tty. If you want an "empty" stdin, test it with `./a.out <&-`. Notice that the if/else are reversed in that code snippet ;-) (and that that's not a reliable way to test whether a file is seekable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//1 ./a.out`:

If you do no redirection of stdin (no pipe and no `<`), stdin is inherited from the parent process. As you run `a.out` interactively in a shell, it inherits the terminal device that gets your keyboard input as stdin.

Terminal devices aren't usually seekable because they represent user interaction, but according to the POSIX standard `lseek` may return success and simply do nothing. On Linux `lseek` fails with an `ESPIPE`.

`//2 ./a.out < /etc/passwd`:

Here stdin is redirected to an open file. As `/etc/passwd` should be a regular file, it is seekable.

`//3 cat < /etc/passwd | ./a.out`:

Here you start two processes (`cat` and `./a.out`) and connect them with a pipe.

`cat` (without other arguments) reads it stdin (`/etc/passwd`) and copies it to its stdout (the pipe connecting to `./a.out`). This is not the same case as `//2`. From the perspective of `./a.out` the stdin cannot seek because it is only a pipe connecting to another process.

`//4 ./a.out < /var/spool/cron/FIFO`:

Here you have a *named pipe* or similar special file. This case is similar to `//3`. You have an unidirectional connection to another process. And these are not seekable.

Comment: Hmm... Is any of this Linux-specific? I get `cannot seek` on the first two and `seek OK` on the last two on OpenBSD.  Maybe I should ask a separate question about that, but if there's a portability issue with the code, it would be good to point this out.

Comment: AFAIK this is not Linux-specific. There were some proposals for „seekable pipes“ but these don't seem to be implemented anywhere by default. But as @Uncle Billy already mentioned, the if-condition is reversed in the code snipped in the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda that code is not portable, but in addition to that, it's printing exactly the reverse ("seek OK" when the lseek() failed and returned -1).

Comment: @cg909 it's not about being able to actually seek on a pipe -- lseek is simply allowed to succeed *without* moving the pointer on devices that don't support seeking. There's no requirement to fail with an error in that case.

Comment: @UncleBilly You're partly right. https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/3P/lseek/
»The behavior of lseek() on devices which are incapable of seeking is implementation-defined.  The value of the file offset associated  with such a device is undefined.« and »Errors: ESPIPE The fildes argument is associated with a pipe, FIFO, or socket.«
So `lseek` on pipes needs to fail with an error, but it isn't defined for terminal devices etc.

Comment: @cg909 you're probably right about pipes (at least with recent version), but I'm pretty sure that seeking on a tty is silently "succeeding" on BSD (even when seeking at random offsets with SEEK_SET).

Comment: with an offset of `0` doing nothing and returning success is the right thing to do. The OS could do this for un-seekably files, if it wanted to (but is it a good ideas). Seeking forward is also easy to implement. The OS would have to throw-away then next n bytes, before continuing to deliver bytes to the process. Seeking backward would need memory.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the reversed statements. But one thing I feel confused that is why is it the question concerning about the files targeted? I don't understand.  Let's say for `//2 ./a.out < /etc/passwd`, I think `stdin` consists of data from `/etc/passwd`. And for  `//3`, `cat < /etc/passwd` pipes all data to the `stdin` of `./a.out`, so I think they are the same.  But you are targeting about another file in `//2` and a pipe in `//3`. Doesn't the code always deal with file descriptor `stdin` and the other command only transit data to it?

Comment: `//2 ./a.out < /etc/passwd`, does it mean that if I use `<` redirection, `stdin` is not involved anymore and the redirected target should now be taken into concern ?

Comment: @Rick when you do `< /etc/passwd`, `/etc/passwd` *is stdin*. You seem to have bought into the idea that stdin is something magic -- it's not. It's simply a file descriptor like any other else. You can replicate the redirection in your program with `fd = open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY); dup2(fd, 0); close(fd)` (error checking ommitted) -- that's basically what bash does.

Comment: @Rick To make you understand better try stracing the following `awk 'BEGIN{print "q" >"/tmp/q"}' <&-`; the `<&-` is closing stdin, causing the next successful open to return `0` aka `stdin`, even if it's open in *write-only mode*.

Comment: @UncleBilly Thanks. I seems to understand more by reading your first replying comment again and again. And the second comment does not help much. :) But it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Rick I don't see what's the problem with the my comments. Have you tried it? If you `close(0)` (`STDIN_FILENO` is just a pedantic way of writing `0`), the next `open()` (or `socket()` or `inotify_init()` or any system call returning a file descriptor) will return `0` aka "standard input", even if it's not a fd you can get any input from. That was supposed to dispell the idea that `stdin` is an intermediary entity that "consists of data" of some file, and to help you understand that the "standard fds" are simply a convention which is **not** enforced by the OS.